# getElementById from a button inside an innerHTML list

Tags: javascript, html, gis, arcgis-js-api

I need to reset a user entered variable that is inside an innerHTML list that is being called by a expand function from the esri JavaScript API.

[image]

This code is building the expand widget

```
// Displays instructions to the user for understanding the sample
// And places them in an Expand widget instance
const sampleInstructions = document.createElement('div');
sampleInstructions.style.padding = '10px';
sampleInstructions.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(12, 32, 116, 0.6)';
sampleInstructions.style.color = '#dbdbdb';
sampleInstructions.style.fontFamily = 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
sampleInstructions.style.width = '450px';
sampleInstructions.innerHTML = [
    '<div class="instruct">',
    'Use the input below to designate the buffer distance (in miles) to aggregate all variables (in right side panel).<br><br>',
    '</div>',
    '<div class="inputDiv">',
    '<label for="userInput" class="userInputLabel">Set Buffer Radius (miles) for Aggregation</label>',
    '<input type="number" id="input-number" class="radiusInput" placeholder="Radius" min="0" step="0.5"></input>',
    '<button type="button" id= clear> Click here to clear </button>',

    '</div>'
].join(' ');
```

This code works if I have a button that is not in the widget:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('clear')
ele.addEventListener('click', clearGeometry);


// Clear the geometry and set the default renderer
function clearGeometry() {
    clearCharts();
    document.getElementById('input-number').value = ''
    if (highlightHandle) {
        highlightHandle.remove();
        highlightHandle = null;
    }
}
```

This code adds the widget to the web app

```
const instructionsExpand = new Expand({
    expandIconClass: 'esri-icon-description',
    expandTooltip: 'Set Aggregate Buffer',
    view: view,
    content: sampleInstructions,
    expanded: view.widthBreakpoint !== 'xsmall'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be is that the Expand widget is dynamically loading the html elements which are not loaded in the DOM in the page load. Hence, you must bind the click event to the whole document not that particular clear button.

```
document.addEventListener("click", event => {
    if(event.target.id == 'clear') clearGeometry();
});

// Clear the geometry and set the default renderer
function clearGeometry() {
    clearCharts();
    document.getElementById('input-number').value = ''
    if (highlightHandle) {
        highlightHandle.remove();
        highlightHandle = null;
    }
}
```